# How do I convert a Rails DateTime object to an XML string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, datetime

I have a DateTime object in Rails which outputs like this when called:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Time.now
 => Wed Nov 10 16:46:51 -0800 2010
```

How do I convert the DateObject to return an XML datetime type string like this:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p302 > Time.now.convert_to_xml
 => 2010-11-10T16:46:51-08:00
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Time to XML format:

```
Time.now.xmlschema # implemented by Rails, not stock ruby
Time.now.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#M000281

To parse (Ruby 1.9 and beyond):

```
t = Time.now.xmlschema(str)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Time.html#M000329

Comment: Looks like Time.now.xmlschema works in Ruby 1.8.7 too. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `Time.xmlschema` is implemented as an extension to the `Time` class by Rails. It's not stock Ruby. I updated the answer.

Comment: The method with strftime, although verbose, is needed for some xml applications. E.g., epub 3 requires Z on the end rather than a numerical timezone.

Comment: The Rails version is incorrect. XML specification is xs:dateTime and must be in UTC without time zone information. `Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Time.now.xmlschema
 => "2013-05-11T00:44:23+02:00"` "xs:dateTime, which is built in to the W3C XML Schema Data types
specification [Schema2], and MUST be expressed in UTC form, with no timezone component."

Answer (score 6):

Try `Time.now.iso8601`

Comment: This is nice succinct answer too!

Comment: "xs:dateTime, which is built in to the W3C XML Schema Data types
specification [Schema2], and MUST be expressed in UTC form, with no timezone component."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure-Ruby way:

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

You can get more details about the various strftime options with:

```
ri Time.strftime
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298) method

```
Time.now.strftime("your format string")
```

Comment: to_s doesn't convert to xml. I just get the same response as `Time.now` but in quotes `"Wed Nov 10 16:46:51 -0800 2010"`